# Convert JSON made by PHP "json_encode", into array to plot those values with D3

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I know, there are so many question like this, but I still haven't understand how to plot my json with D3.

Well, this is the PHP:

```
$sth = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Time AS x, Value AS y FROM dati WHERE Data='2006-09-26' AND SensorType=6");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

this give me a json that I can see by an js alert:

```
[{"x":"11:35:27","y":"500"},{"x":"11:40:40","y":"263"},{"x":"11:55:10","y":"440"},{"x":"12:11:34","y":"1063"},{"x":"12:16:48","y":"1065"},{"x":"12:22:01","y":"1121"}]
```

and the fallows is my "wrong" json that has requested the json and made the alert:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "json.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
                alert(obj);
 }
```

Now, if i try to plot obj with d3 (or whatever I guess) it doesn't work,
I think that's because obj is NOT in the right format.

is there anyone so kind to help me?
My goal is to plot those value in an LineChart

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "json.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(obj);
 }
```

or this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "json.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
             dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);
 }
```

Comment: I tried without stringify, and it does return: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Try this if your respons json string this code worked

Comment: Yes this true you need can console.log(data) for see object, alert can's see object this is true

Comment: for alert you can try this alert(data[0].x);

Comment: You're right! Thanks, now I'm trying to plot data, d3 seems to be powerful, but not that easy to use